# Map positioned, but not zooming

Tags: android, google-maps

From a Thread I start some code on UI in order to zoom a map and to position it.
While the positioning works fine (New York), the zoom is ignored (always half of the globe). I have tried with all possible zoomOld values, but it's all the time the same. What is wrong in my code?

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    zoomOld = 1;
                    CameraUpdate forget = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomOld);

                    map.animateCamera(forget);

                    double targetLat = 40.7;

                    double targetLon = -74.1;

                    LatLng p = new LatLng(targetLat,// 3.0.1
                            targetLon);
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(p));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in my case works fine.Hope this to help you.

```
 CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(mCongressLocation).zoom(16).build();

  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

Comment: This works indeed. Thanks a lot. But according to doc, it should have worked. Maybe doc is wrong?

Comment: Maybe which doc you read to use this kind of zooming the map ?

Comment: From doc at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views

// Zoom out to zoom level 10, animating with a duration of 2 seconds.
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);